# SASS Parent Selector not working in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I want to style my navigation component using SASS. Did the required configuration and also installed the sass package (npm install sass). Then imported the styles to my component:

```
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss";
```

And this is the Navigation component:

```
const Navigation = (props) => {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className={styles.navbar}>
            <div>
              <Link href="/">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div >
              <ul>
                <Link href="/about-us">
                  <a className={styles.navbarLink}>About Us</a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/">
                  <a className={styles.navbarLink}>About Us</a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/services">
                  <a className={styles.navbarLink}>Services</a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/certificates">
                  <a className={styles.navbarLink}>Certificates</a>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/how-we-build">
                  <a className={styles.navbarLink}>How we build</a>
                </Link>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
```

My anchor styles are not being applied properly, I tried:

```
&-link { // & is the parent selector (.navbar)
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0cc6ff;
}
```

And

```
.navbar-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0cc6ff;
}
```

And when I

```
console.log(styles.navbarLink) // shows undefined
```

**Creating seperate '.class' without the nesting or just selecting the '.navbar a' works.**

**Am I doing something wrong or NextJs doesn't somehow support the '&' sass feature?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with SASS, instead of styling like this:

```
 <a className={styles.navbarLink}>Certificates</a>
```

I can style the anchor tag like this:

```
<a className={styles['navbar-link']}>Certificates</a>
```